# Cannot install ReSharper Ultimate Extensions (Exceptional) in Visual Studio 2019 and 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, extension, resharper

I have installed ReSharper Ultimate (version 2019.2) via Jetbrains for Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 (tried it on different machines with different VS installations).

I want to install the [Exceptional extension for ReSharper](https://github.com/CSharpAnalyzers/ExceptionalReSharper).
Installation instruction:

```
Open the ReSharper menu in Visual Studio and select Extension Manager...
Search for Exceptional and install the extension
```

(The following  descripes the situation for VS 2019, but VS 2017 is analog)
When I open the ReSharper extension manager it says that 55 extensions are available and the tab "Most Popular" ist selected.
If I enter "Exceptional" in the search bar I get no results.

Can you give me any hints how I can install this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you give me any hints on how I can install this extension?

The extension has not been updated to support ReSharper 2019.2.2 based on the last update it only supports versions before and including ReSharper 2019.1.1.

**In order for the extension to be visible you will have to update the extension yourself or wait for the author to do it.**